# how to create new magento structural blocks to change theme layout?

Tags: magento-1.9, theme

I have problem with magento  layout xml. I want to  create custom structural blocks as accomplish following. I want to create custom as following.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For creating custom structural blocks you can take help from http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-reference-structural-block/

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: This is my go to article even though Ive done this a hundred times I always fall back to this little gem from inchoo

Comment: please let  me  try....

Comment: It  not properly answered and  you have put  reference link as answer ... Please put some details.. Other put this as comment